# Give rise to an event on all tabs on same namespace (browser/domain), but not on the tab that triggered it

Tags: javascript, events, tabs, local-storage

```
window.onstorage = () => {
    alert("A storage event from another tab!")
};
```

A storage event never executes within the tab that triggered it, instead it gets called in all other tabs on the same "namespace" (browser/domain. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event).

How can I do the same but with my own custom event (x happens and then all other tabs on same namespace give rise to an event)?

Comment: The storage event does not fire on the page that sets it. So it should just work the way you want it to. So what is the issue you face?

Answer (score 0):

Using localStorage along with the onstorage event is one way of broadcasting messages amongst tabs. However, you are enforced to encode/parse the message using JSON.stringify/JSON.parse. This prevents you from sending non-stringifiable objects like Blobs, Files etc. Also, the size of localStorage is limited (~10MB).

There is a better approach for this purpose, which is very similar to the postMessage API, called [Broadcast Channel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API). An example on how you can create your own event notification system:

```
// Window 1
const bc = new BroadcastChannel('my_channel'); // connect to my_channel
bc.postMessage({eventType: "myEvent", eventData: "Hi, this is an event"});

// Window 2
const bc = new BroadcastChannel('my_channel'); // connect to my_channel
bc.onmessage = function (ev) { 
  if(ev.data.eventType == "myEvent"){ // only listen for myEvent
    console.log("Event myEvent received.");
    console.log("Information of the event: %s", ev.data.eventData);
  }
}
```

Notice that both windows must be connected to the same channel (in this case "my_channel"), and both windows must have the same origin.